# Autowiring not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Please help me with this error, I'm new to spring.

This the stack trace:

```
12:23:16,350 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at igate.service.ProgramsOfferedServiceImpl.retrievePrograms(ProgramsOfferedServiceImpl.java:39)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jsp.programs_jsp._jspService(programs_jsp.java:118)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    12:23:16,351 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    12:23:16,352 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    12:23:16,352 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    12:23:16,352 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    12:23:16,352 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    12:23:16,352 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
    12:23:16,352 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    12:23:16,352 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This the code for data access:

```
package igate.dao;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import igate.dto.ProgramsOffered;
@Component
public class ProgramsOfferedDataAccessImpl implements ProgramsOfferedDataAccess 
{
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate template;

    public ProgramsOfferedDataAccessImpl() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    System.out.println("inside programs offered");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean DeleteProgramsOffered(String name)throws SQLException 
    {
        boolean rowsAffected = false;
        String delete = "DELETE FROM programs_offered WHERE program_name='"+name+"'";
        int r = template.update(delete);
        if(r>0)
            rowsAffected=true;
        return rowsAffected;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<ProgramsOffered> retrievePrograms() 
    {
        RowMapper<ProgramsOffered> row = new RowMapper<ProgramsOffered>()
        {

            @Override
            public ProgramsOffered mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException 
            {
                ProgramsOffered po = new ProgramsOffered();
                po.setProgramName(rs.getString(1));
                po.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
                po.setApplicantEligibility(rs.getString(3));
                po.setDuration(rs.getInt(4));
                po.setDegreeCertificateOffered(rs.getString(5));
                return po;
            }

        };
        String sql = "select * from programs_offered";
        System.out.println(template);
        return (ArrayList<ProgramsOffered>)template.query(sql, row);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insertProgram(ProgramsOffered po) 
    {
        boolean rowsAffected = false;
        String insert = "insert into programs_offered values(?,?,?,?,?)";
        int r = template.update(insert);
        if(r>0)
            rowsAffected=true;
        return rowsAffected;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateProgram(String progName, String colName, String newValue) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateProgram(String progName, String colName, int newValue) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getTemplate() 
    {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) 
    {
        this.template = template;
    }
}
```

This is my service layer. I am not able to get what the problem is here as I am auto wiring `ProgramsOffered poda` but I am still getting null pointer exception.

```
package igate.service;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import igate.dao.*;
import igate.dto.ProgramsOffered;
@Component("offeredService")
public class ProgramsOfferedServiceImpl implements ProgramsOfferedService 
{
    @Autowired
    public ProgramsOfferedDataAccess poda;


    @Override
    public boolean DeleteProgramsOffered(String name)
    {
        boolean rowsaffected=false;
        try
        {
            rowsaffected = poda.DeleteProgramsOffered(name);

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rowsaffected;
    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<ProgramsOffered> retrievePrograms() 
    {
        ArrayList<ProgramsOffered> al = poda.retrievePrograms();
        return al;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean insertProgram(ProgramsOffered po) 
    {

        return poda.insertProgram(po);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean updateProgram(String progName, String colName, String newValue) 
    {

        return poda.updateProgram(progName, colName, newValue);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean updateProgram(String progName, String colName, int newValue) 
    {

        return poda.updateProgram(progName, colName, newValue);
    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<ProgramsOffered> programDetails(String programName) 
    {
        ArrayList<ProgramsOffered> list = new ArrayList<ProgramsOffered>();
        list = poda.retrievePrograms();
        System.out.println("to keep at 0 "+programName);
        System.out.println("list size:" +list.size());
        int size = list.size();
        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            if(!list.get(i).getProgramName().trim().equals(programName))
            {
                System.out.println("removing: "+list.get(i).getProgramName());
                //list.remove(i);
            }
            else
            {
                ProgramsOffered temp = new ProgramsOffered();
                temp = list.get(0);
                list.set(0, list.get(i));
                list.set(i, temp);
                System.out.println("at 0 prog: "+list.get(0));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }


}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception on this line:
`ArrayList<ProgramsOffered> al = poda.retrievePrograms();`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

            <mvc:annotation-driven />
            <context:annotation-config/>
            <context:component-scan base-package="igate.dto" />
                <context:component-scan base-package="igate.dao" />
                    <context:component-scan base-package="igate.service" />
                        <context:component-scan base-package="igate.controller" />
                <context:component-scan base-package="igate.logs" />
                    <context:component-scan base-package="igate.testcases" />


            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                  <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
                  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean> 


            <bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.17.5:1521:oraten" />
                <property name="username" value="lab01trg21" />
                <property name="password" value="lab01oracle" />
            </bean>

            <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"/>
            </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: From where are you calling this method? Judging from the stacktrace you are trying to call your service from a JSP. Judging from that is that you are constructing an instance yourself in the JSP and expect Spring to automagically wire that, you should use the one from the applicationcontext. Or even better don't do stuff like that in your View layer, that should be left to the `(@)Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Does your applicationContext.xml (or dispatcher-servlet.xml) contain the following lines:

```
<!-- Use annotation based configuration (e.g. @Service, @Component etc.) -->
<context:annotation-config/>
<!-- Autowire beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="igate.service"/>
```

Comment: i ve added my context.xml

Answer (score -1):

You do nothave the setters and getters for poda. Without setters and getters Spring cannot autowire

Comment: added setters and getters still getting error at ArrayList al = poda.retrievePrograms();